# Markdown does not display formulas correctly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

A formula written as $$\bold{x}$$ in Jupyter Lab is displayed as \bold{x} instead of a bold x when Markdown is compiled. I tried another character, but got same result,

I consulted ChatGPT, but the issue was not resolved.

Comment: ChatGPT just strings words together. It has _no understanding, whatsoever_. Don't trust it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the Jupyter Notebook markdown cell, ** x ** (without spaces) will appear as **x**.  Not familiar with Jupyter Lab, but this might work.

Comment: But,  **x** can't used in $$equation$$...

Answer (score 0):

Was self resolved. I should have typed `\mathbf` instead of `\bold`.